# Redirect using a path

Tags: 8, routes, redirection

My question seems to be obvious but I really don't find the solution.
Well, I want to redirect to my view just after connexion.
I try to use $form_state->setRedirect,but It's seems it needs the route name. 
I don't find the route name of my view!
How to get a route name from a path? Or to redirect using the path?

Comment: no in this link, they say to use a route name. I don't know how to get the route name!

Comment: The route is `view.[view_id].[display_id]`. You find the machine name of the display in the advanced section. This is most times `page_1`. An example is `view.frontpage.page_1` for the view of the frontpage.

Comment: thank you, but it doen't work I'm having this error : "Route "......" does not exist :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use setRedirectUrl(), which needs a URL object. There are many ways to create one, for example for an arbitrary path: `Url::fromUri('base:some/path')`